# Temporary SSL for Windows 2000 Server/IIS Classic ASP pages?

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis-5, windows-server-2000

I've got to set up temporary SSL security on my classic ASP application on Windows 2000 server, IIS5. What do I need to do to activate SSL? I won't be able to get an official cert for a little while so I think I have to make my own.

Steps? Do I need access to the router or anything or can I just do this through IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299525) to explain the procedure, assuming you are running (or can activate) certificate services. If you don't have certificate services, you can generate a server certificate with OpenSSL, and use that as step 2 (you would need to generate a self-signed CA certificate first). However, it should also be possible to skip both step 1 and 2 with OpenSSL, by using a self-signed certificate.